# How to Deploy Node.js app in Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: .net, node.js, linux, ubuntu

How to Deploy Node.js app in Ubuntu/Linux? which is developed in the .net framework without the use of docker?

Thank you for giving your great time.

Comment: What do you mean a Node.js app that was developed in the .net framework?

Comment: i have developed a node.js app in .net and need to deploy it in ubuntu server.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'a Node.js app in .NET'? Unless you've got some kind of integration layer, like what @0x616f mentioned, they're two completely unrelated technologies. Be more specific, and you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

A very useful tool to assist in deploying .NET framed Node.JS application is: http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/

`RUN NODE.JS AND .NET IN-PROCESS`

The real question is why you would want to destroy the portability of Node.JS by introducing .NET.